# Does getting less rows from database increase performance?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a simple question. Assume that the following sql returns over milion records:

```
Select * from Table
```

If I only need to work with 100 records, will limiting rows increase significantly the performance and why ?

Example oracle sql :

```
Select * from Table where rownum<=100
```

Comment: Generate and compare the execution plans for the two SQLs. You will know the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are reading all the rows, then limiting the number of rows will be more efficient.

If you are reading the rows through -- say -- a cursor, then you probably will not see any difference in performance.

If your "table" is really a "view", then the two queries might optimize differently.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I noticed that when running the sql in oracle sql developer the one with rownum was executing more then 10 times faster on 30k records table. So is this the same for every database ?

Comment: @MasterYi . . . It is returning all the rows, which takes a lot more time.

Answer (score 0):

No . The best way to find an answer is quickly generate an Explain plan . And see the relative cost of execution . It will give you the quick view . Returning row is display part but fetching of the row done on the condition . So preferably it will not be slower and it attest what i am saying generate the explain plan it will give the clear picture